# Can I save system app data from being erased?

Tags: applications, factory-reset

I have app that is installed in the system , my question if there is a way to prevent factory reset from erasing app data , no need to change the settings again ,without using backup app , atomic process after the phone has started working after factory reset

Comment: App data is saved on `/data` partition which is completely erased with factory reset. So there is no way to retain data except backup/restore (backup app isn't necessarily required) or devise some way to make data available on boot from some other source which is not erased with factory reset e.g. external SD card or some partition on internal storage.

Comment: Can you explain more? if there is a specific way that i can restore data without using backup app it would be so helpful

Comment: Use adb backup, create tar file from commandline, manually copy paste data directory of the app from custom recovery, create a flashable zip to backup/restore data easily etc. Possibly other approaches too.